# Sort an array of mixed (empty and non-empty) cstrings

Tags: c++, c-strings

I am trying to put the empty (`example[0] == '\0'`) c-strings in the back of the array instead of the front while keeping the sort order ascending. I am using `strcmp(...)` to compare the current cstring to the next cstring in the array using a simple selection sort, but would like to be able to apply this to other types of sorts as well

*edit-- tempword is actually an object instead of a char* in my code, but this should be functionally equivalent*

```
sortList() {
   char *tempword = new char[30];
   int min;

   for (int i=0; i<(d_length-1); ++i) {
      min = i;

      for (int j=i+1; j<d_length; ++j) {

         if ((strcmp(d_wordlist[min], d_wordlist[j]) > 0)) {
         min = j;
         }
      }

      if (min != i) {

         *tempword = d_wordlist[min];

         d_wordlist[min] = d_wordlist[i];

         d_wordlist[i] = *tempword;
      }
   }
   delete[] tempword;
}
```

*edit 2-- I ended up making a wrapper function for strcmp as suggested by "im so confused".

```
int compare(const char* str1, const char* str2) {
   if (str2[0] == '\0')
      return -1;
   return strcmp(str1, str2);
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code you have so far?

Comment: create your own custom compare function that orders as you wish, then pass that function pointer to the sorting function of your choice, a la qsort

Comment: to clarify, it could be as simple as a wrapper function that checks if the string is null, if so it's automatically greater, then just calls strcmp

Comment: Are you trying to sort letters in a word or are you sorting a list of words?

Comment: Im trying to sort a list of words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The straight-forward approach is to have your `sortList` function take a custom comparison function. Your custom comparison function should return false if the left operand is an empty string `""`. If the left operand is not empty but the right operand is empty than return true. Otherwise just do a regular string comparison.

For example, using `std::string` this comparison function should do the trick:

```
bool comp(const std::string &lhs, const std::string &rhs)
{
  if (lhs == "") return false;
  return rhs == "" || !(rhs < lhs);
}
```

Note that you'll need to fix your `sortList` to swap words instead of letters to get what you're looking for.

Comment: I adjusted this for using char\* instead strings and it worked great. I've added my adjusted compare function as an edit to the original question.

Comment: The swap portion of the sortList() I wrote above should use strcpy or similar instead of assignment... in my original each word is an object w/ overloaded assignment... I was trying to generalize here